# What good tiny or basic SVG editors are there?

Tags: editor, svg, specifications

I'm in need for a good SVG editor which can produce valid xml according to spec of the Tiny SVG profile.

I would prefer if the tool was open-source or free but good commercial tools are welcome as well.

Note: I have used some online tools and Inkscape, but those do not allow specifying the spec they must adhere to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_editors

Here is another link.He explaints how to install and use a tool to convert inkscape svg to svg-t. Hope this helps :)

http://gnugos60.blogspot.com/2007/02/inkscape-and-svg2svgt.html

If you can, there is a commercial solution. Adobe Illustrator can save files as SVG-t.
[http://www.amazon.com/Adobe-Illustrator-CS2-OLD-VERSION/dp/B00081G3V6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00081G3V6) (see Product features)

Comment: Thanks but I've already looked at that list and it's not clear which ones support the tiny SVG spec. I'm asking because people developing for mobiles probably know the answer...

Comment: That's true, i've just found out myself that illustrator supports it. Good stuff, thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an online web site. Free. I tried it in Chrome. Very handy.

[Svg-Editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html)

The project site is [here](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/)